# how to pass multiple field with onchange

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is my HTML code:  (it only passes the dropdown menu to php, I also need to pass the hidden field. Looked everywhere on the web... couldn't find the answer.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="reply">
        <select name="status" class="form-field" onchange="reply.submit();" >
                 <option selected value="0">Make a Selection</option>
                 <option value="Approve">Approve</option>
                 <option value="1">Modify</option>
                 <option value="Decline">Decline</option>
                  <input type="hidden" value="test"/>
        </select>
                     <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="reply" ></noscript> 
                     </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

give the hidden a field a name and move it outside of the select. You need the name for the browser to see the form field.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

It should look like this then

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I don't want the submit button, I want to send the info when the dropdown is selected automatically ... this is why I want to use onchange

Answer (score 0):

You need to include name='hiddenFieldName'.

Answer (score 0):

Please try executing sample code snippet

```
<form action="" method="post" name="reply">
      <select name="status" class="form-field" onchange="demo(this.form)" >
             <option selected value="0">Make a Selection</option>
             <option value="Approve">Approve</option>
             <option value="1">Modify</option>
             <option value="Decline">Decline</option>
              <input type="hidden" name="demo_field" value="test"/>
      </select>
                 <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="reply" ></noscript> 
                 </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function demo(formobj)
   {
      alert(formobj.demo_field.value);
   }
 </script>
```